# Do I need to run db:test:prepare each time I run rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I lately got back into rails and as I remember it, once you setup your database DEV and TEST each migration you do it would be enough to just call bundle exec rspec.

But now, when I do that, I keep getting this error:

```
/Users/kgan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/formatters/base_formatter.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `require_rspec_core' for RSpec::Support:Module (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/kgan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/kgan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /Users/kgan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/kgan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/kgan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-extra-formatters-1.0.0/lib/rspec-extra-formatters/junit_formatter.rb:30:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/kgan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/kgan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /Users/kgan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/kgan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/kgan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-extra-formatters-1.0.0/lib/rspec-extra-formatters.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/kgan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.9/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
    from /Users/kgan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.9/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/kgan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.9/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from /Users/kgan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.9/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from /Users/kgan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.9/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from /Users/kgan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.9/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from /Users/kgan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.9/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
    from /Users/kgan/Git/level_up_exercises/cyoa/the_honey_hour/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/kgan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.2/lib/spring/application.rb:82:in `require'
    from /Users/kgan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.2/lib/spring/application.rb:82:in `preload'
    from /Users/kgan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.2/lib/spring/application.rb:143:in `serve'
    from /Users/kgan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.2/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
    from /Users/kgan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.2/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
    from /Users/kgan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.2/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
    from /Users/kgan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.2/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/kgan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/kgan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
Coverage report generated for RSpec to /Users/kgan/Git/level_up_exercises/cyoa/the_honey_hour/coverage. 6 / 10 LOC (60.0%) covered.
/Users/kgan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:393:in `check_pending!':  (ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError)

Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run:

    bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test

    from /Users/kgan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:406:in `load_schema_if_pending!'
    from /Users/kgan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:412:in `block in maintain_test_schema!'
    from /Users/kgan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:640:in `suppress_messages'
    from /Users/kgan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:417:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/kgan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:412:in `maintain_test_schema!'
    from /Users/kgan/Git/level_up_exercises/cyoa/the_honey_hour/spec/rails_helper.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/kgan/Git/level_up_exercises/cyoa/the_honey_hour/spec/models/user_spec.rb:1:in `require'
    from /Users/kgan/Git/level_up_exercises/cyoa/the_honey_hour/spec/models/user_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/kgan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `load'
    from /Users/kgan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /Users/kgan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `each'
    from /Users/kgan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/kgan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:96:in `setup'
    from /Users/kgan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:84:in `run'
    from /Users/kgan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
    from /Users/kgan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:37:in `invoke'
    from /Users/kgan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/kgan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
    from /Users/kgan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
```

But after running db:test:prepare, it becomes ok. Any ideas or is this the new default behavior of Rails in the test environment?

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily, just run it every time your schema gets updated or you have a new migration file. It basically handles the cloning of your database so you don't have to run migration on your test database.

Comment: That's the thing, I did. But each time I run the spec it gives me that error, and when I do run it I am able to run the test then if I wish to do it again, I have to do db:test:prepare all over again.

Comment: That's weird, you should really run the command when you have pending migrations. Maybe you haven't run `rake db:migrate` yet? I'm really stomped as well.

Comment: I did, I ran it like more than 10 times now. I don't know. So confused at this point.

Comment: Got it sorted out, I removed the rspec-legacy-formatters gem and the rspec-extra-formatters and works great now. So weird.